# pull youtube video title into page

Tags: php, api, parsing, youtube

I am pulling in some youtube video thumbnails into my page with the following:

```
<img src="http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/<?php echo $youtubelist[$i];?>/default.jpg"></img>
```

(using a Joomla module to supply the youtube video ID's at $youtubelist)

Along with the youtube thumbnail, I also want to pull in the youtube video 'title' & 'description'.

How do I do this?

Thanks

[edited below]

This is my code & I want to place the title above the  tag:

```
<?php
$youtubelist    = explode( ',', $youtubecode );
$numyoutube     = count($youtubelist);
//Get duplicate module or not
$a=1;
foreach ($list as $item) :
    //$total=$a;
    $enddbid = $item->id;
        if ($ytslide==$enddbid) {$nummod=$a;}
    $a++;   
endforeach;
?>
<div id="videos">
    <div style="padding-left: 2px; padding-right: 2px;padding-bottom:2px;">
    <?php for ($i=0; $i<$numyoutube; $i++) { ?>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/<?php echo $youtubelist[$i];?>/default.jpg"></img>
        </a>
    <?php } ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Read : YouTube API https://developers.google.com/youtube/

Comment: which joomla module are you using for this...???

Comment: It is a module that has been built for me - but the dev has disappeared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get information about a particular youtube video using this piece of code:

```
$url = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/$youtubeid?v=2";
$res = file_get_contents($url);
```

This will return Atom XML with the full metadata of the video, including title, author, dates, keywords, etc., etc.  Read the `<title>` element of the response to get what you need.  So this code will give you what you're after:

```
$data = new DOMDocument();
$res = preg_replace('/>\s+</','><', $res);
$root = $req->loadXML($res);
$tnodes = $root->getElementsByTagName('title');
$tn = $tnodes->item(0);
$title = $tn->firstChild->nodeValue;
```

With your code you'll need to have something like this:

```
<div id="videos">
    <div style="padding-left: 2px; padding-right: 2px;padding-bottom:2px;">
    <?php
        $data = new DOMDocument();
        for ($i=0; $i<$numyoutube; $i++) {
            $url = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/" . $youtubelist[$i] . "?v=2";
            $res = file_get_contents($url);
            $res = preg_replace('/>\s+</','><', $res);
            $root = $req->loadXML($res);
            $tnodes = $root->getElementsByTagName('title');
            $tn = $tnodes->item(0);
            $title = $tn->firstChild->nodeValue;
        ?>
        <a href="#">
            <div style="float:left">
                <?php echo $title; ?>
                <br/>
                <img src="http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/<?php echo $youtubelist[$i];?>/default.jpg" />
            </div>
        </a>
    <?php } ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks... can I do anything with a url/php - just to grab the video title to go with my above image?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  I've gone through this issue some time ago - and had to use XML feed to get info (I only needed one field out of that feed, too, but had to parse the lot to get the value).

Comment: @PramodKumarSharma I updated my answer to include the code to read tht title

Comment: Thanks @Aleks G - really appreciated. How would I then echo the title, along with my original <img> with php? (i'm a php newbie, sorry)

Comment: Well, you'd just `echo $title` - but I can't say more without seeing your code.

Comment: I have edited my original post & have included the code (partial) that I am using. I want to place the title above the <img> tag.

Comment: You will need to do quite a bit more HTML here to achieve what you want.  You'll need to put each video thumbnail with its title into a separate div, most likely floating. I'm updating my answer to give you the idea of what to do, but it's not the final solution.  You'll have to figure out for yourself how to achieve the final result.

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch the youtube video info by passing the video id in this

```
$video_feed = file_get_contents("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/$videoid");
                $sxml = new SimpleXmlElement($video_feed);

                //set up nodes
                $namespaces = $sxml->getNameSpaces(true);
                $media = $sxml->children($namespaces['media']);
                $yt = $media->children($namespaces['yt']);
                $yt_attrs = $yt->duration->attributes();

                //vars
                 $video_title = $sxml->title;

                 $video_description = $sxml->content;

                 $video_keywords = $media->group->keywords;

                 $video_length = $yt_attrs['seconds'];
```